# Suppose a function has a best constant approximation at a point. Is it continuous at that point?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and suppose $f$ has a best constant approximation at $x$. This means that there is an approximation constant $c$ such that for all other constants $d$ there exists a positive length interval $I$ containing $x$ for which $y \in I$ implies $|f(y)-c| \leq |f(y)-d|$.

Is $f$ continuous at $x$?

Comment: Differentiability of a function at $x$ is often characterised as the fact that a best linear approximation exists there so I wondered if a similar fact is true for continuity. It is easy to prove the other direction.  Note that if $f$ has a BCA at $x$ then it is unique, and it is $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

1. We must have $c = f(x)$. Otherwise we would have $0 < \lvert f(x) - c \rvert$ , but with $d = f(x)$ and $y = x \in I$ we would get $\lvert f(y) - d \rvert < \lvert f(y) - c \rvert$, a contradiction.
2. $f$ must be constant on $I$. To see this, assume that $f(y) \ne f(x)$ for some $y \in I$. Then with $d = f(y)$ we get $0 = \lvert f(y) - d \rvert < \lvert f(y) - f(x) \rvert = \lvert f(y) - c \rvert$, a contradiction.